# Rails 5 ActiveStorage: Why does my form forget the selected file when the page is re-rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage to implement file uploads in a form.

```
<%= form_for @listing do |form| %>
  # ...
  <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
  <%= form.file_field :image, direct_upload: true, accept: "image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

I handle the form submission in the controller like so:

```
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(safe_params)
    if @listing.save
      flash[:success] = "Your posting has been submitted"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = @listing.errors.full_messages
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

If validations fail, the new page is re-rendered. If I've already entered a title, the previously entered title is present in the re-rendered form. However, if I've already selected a file, that file is not selected in the re-rendered form.

I select a file:

[image: File is selected]

On submission, the file is uploaded but validation fails and the page is re-rendered. The file is no longer selected:

[image: File is no longer selected]

I'm not quite sure what's going on here. Why isn't the file remembered when the new page is re-rendered? Why doesn't the form display the selected file? What do I need to do to ensure it's still selected when the page re-renders?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<%= form_for @listing do |form| %>
  # ...
  <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :image, value: form.object.image.signed_id if form.object.image.attached? %>
  <%= form.file_field :image, direct_upload: true, accept: "image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with browser 
you can think it as -

> File field as a one-way field. Browser to server, but not server to
>   browser.

That's not how a file field works in any browser.

So on edit page you would have to explicitly preview `file` or `file name` at any other place just to let user know that there is already a file present unless he want to update that with another file.

```
<%= form_for @listing do |form| %>
   #...
    <div>
      <%if form.object.image.present?%>
        #name of file
      <%end%>
    </div>
    <%= form.file_field :image, direct_upload: true, accept: "image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" %>
    #..
<%end%>
```

Comment: How do you display the name of the file?